# How to $compile html template and append to DOM with AJAX return JSON array (List widget add items)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation

Meet this very puzzle question. What I want to do is like following code:

```
$scope.addArtis = function(list) {
    list.forEach(function(article){
        $scope.article = article;
        var html = $compile($templateCache.get('template/articlelist/articleitem.html'))($scope);
            $element.append(html);
        });
    };
};
```

While the template is a string-html-template stored in cache.

**[list]** is the data return by ajax request, that will be a json array. Now to every array object, to compile a different template and append it to DOM.

But now the code result is that I got **[list.length]** same data(last object in JSON array) compiled HTML that been appended to DOM. I'm thinking maybe the **$scope.article** is changed to last JSON array object, But I don't know how to deal with that?

I find if in HTML template using ng-repeat can do some work-around. But what if I just want to compile single and append to DOM in a for loop?

Comment: Try creating a new scope in the loop with $rootScope.new()

Comment: @samschonstal can you give me some code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
.controller('myController', function($rootScope)  {   

$scope.addArtis = function(list) {
    list.forEach(function(article){
        var scope = $rootScope.new();
        scope.article = article;
        var html = $compile($templateCache.get('template/articlelist/articleitem.html'))(scope);
            $element.append(html);
        });
    };
};
});
```

Comment: Thanks sam. With that I got the page work correctly.